# sobrecargar operador []

Tags: c++

Tengo una clase texto

```
class Texto{
private:
    char* texto;
public:
    Texto(char[]);
    Texto(Texto*);
    ~Texto();
    char* getTexto();
    void setTexto(char*);
    char operator [] (int);    
};
```

```
char Texto::operator [](int a){
    return this->texto[a];
}
```

estoy tratando de sobrecargar el operador [] para que dado un numero entero me retorne el caracter que se encuentra en dicha posición pero me da error,en el main no se como pasarle el numero entero,he probado asi

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Texto.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char text[10]={'l','e','o','n','a','r','\0'};

    Texto* t = new Texto(text);

    char c=(*t[]2);
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

cualquier ayuda es bienvenida,saludos

Comment: ¿Qué error te da?

Comment: ya pude solucionarlo

Comment: Eso no responde mi pregunta.

Comment: no me interesa responderte si ya lo solucioné

Comment: Pues vale. Tu respuesta y presunta solución es incorrecta, por mucho que funcione. Pero tú mismo con tu mecanismo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por lo que leí el operador sub índice [] debe retornar una referencia,entonces hice las siguientes modificacions

en el .cpp

```
char& Texto::operator[](int index) 
{ 
    return this->texto[index]; 
}
```

en el .h

```
    char& operator [] (int);
```

y en el main al puntero de tipo texto llamado "t" lo tuve que poner entre paréntesis y el entero iba dentro del operador

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Texto.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char text[10]={'l','e','o','n','a','r','\0'};

    Texto *t =new Texto(text);

    char c=((*t)[2]);
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```